# how to get the process group leader of a thread

Tags: process, linux-kernel

In linux kernel, we can use current->comm to get the name of the process currently running. Could this be a thread under a normal process? Linux has this light-weight process concept, which means thread is also a process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access group leader information of a thread you can use "current->group_leader". In Linux, threads are just another process but shares "memory" group_leader.

Pthread function calls "clone" system call with CLONE_VM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Generally `comm` will be the same for all threads in a process, but it is possible to change it for a thread using `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, ...)`.